# How to Observe Properties of Objects within an ReactiveList

Tags: reactiveui

I have the following Problem. I have got 
a`ProductionOrderList = new ReactiveList<ProductionOrderViewModel>();`

the `ProductionOrderViewModel` has a Property Itemsleft, which gets updated internally

```
    private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<int> itemsLeft;


    public int ItemsLeft => this.itemsLeft.Value;
```

...

```
    this.itemsLeft = this
             .WhenAny(x => x.Ticks, x => x.Value)
             .ToProperty(this, x => x.ItemsLeft, scheduler: DispatcherScheduler.Current);
```

What i want to accomplish is when ever any item in the List comes to a point where the Itemsleft property is 0, it should be removed from the List.

I tried it this way

```
 ProductionOrderList.ItemChanged.Where(x => x.Sender.ProductionOrder.ItemsLeft ==0)
               .Subscribe(v =>
               {
                  // do stuff
               });
```

but it did not work unfortunately.

Help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I found a working solution, it even seems rigth and clean, though I am totally open for improvements. I have done the following

```
this.WhenAnyObservable(o => o.ProductionOrderList.ItemChanged)
            .Where(x => x.PropertyName == "ItemsLeft")
            .Select(x => x.Sender)
            .Where(x => x.ItemsLeft == 0)
            .Subscribe(x =>
            {
                ProductionOrderList.Remove(x);
            });
```

I hope this helps others which habe a similar problem.